# C++ use a number of arguments in variadic macro (implementing optional argument)

Tags: c++, macros

I am writing some macro (yes I know it's evil, but it helps me make more optimized code) that looks like this:

```
#define HUGGLE_DEBUG(debug, verbosity) if (Huggle::Configuration::HuggleConfiguration->Verbosity >= verbosity) \
                                          Huggle::Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog(debug, verbosity)
```

function `DebugLog(QString, unsigned int Verbosity = 1)` has optional parameter Verbosity and I would like to make it optional in macro as well, so that I can call

```
HUGGLE_DEBUG("some debug text");
```

as well as:

```
HUGGLE_DEBUG("more verbose text", 10);
```

Is it somehow possible? Note: I am using the second variable in macro, but if I didn't have it, I could just substitute it to 1

My idea is to make a variadic macro from this, which would work like this:

```
#define HUGGLE_DEBUG(debug, ...)    Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog(debug, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

which would work but it would kind of not use the optimization I did in first one

Comment: Have you profiled and verified that an `inline` functions really turns out worse than a macro?

Comment: The problem here is that I often use a complicated construction as a parameter, like `DebugLog("some text " + fc_that_returns_text() + " bla")` which itself calls lot of text processing functions. I want to avoid having to call it, unless I am really in debugging mode (that is why I want to wrap the call of function in if block of code), if the function was just inline, the parameter would have to be constructed anyway, then it just wouldn't be used

Comment: No, if the function is inlined, it is replaced *in place.* So the string argument would only be evaluated when the `if` passes. That's the *principle* of inlining.

Comment: Of course the inline function `HUGGLE_DEBUG` would have to be defined in a header file, but that just means that header file would need access to the *declaration* of `Verbosity` and `DebugLog`. It doesn't need their definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you're using a macro already, you probably won't mind a very hacky solution:

```
#define HUGGLE_DEBUG(...) \
  if (Huggle::Configuration::HuggleConfiguration->Verbosity >= ((int)(bool)__VA_ARGS__)) \
    Huggle::Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog(__VA_ARGS__)
```

When called with one argument:

```
HUGGLE_DEBUG("abc")

// expands to

if (Huggle::Configuration::HuggleConfiguration->Verbosity >= ((int)(bool)"abc"))
    Huggle::Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog("abc")
```

`(bool)"abc"` is `true`, so `(int)(bool)"abc"` is `1`.

When called with two arguments:

```
HUGGLE_DEBUG("abc", 10)

// expands to

if (Huggle::Configuration::HuggleConfiguration->Verbosity >= ((int)(bool)"abc", 10))
    Huggle::Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog("abc", 10)
```

`(int)(bool)"abc", 10` uses the comma operator, so it evaluates to `10`.

But *please* **please**, consider using an `inline` function instead. There's no need to use a macro for this.

Comment: This solution kills the performance tweak as it needs to evaluate the argument anyway (during if - the first argument, which isn't a text but instance of QString may be complex, include concatenation through overload of + operator, or some other functions that needs to be called). But the last sentence is correct. Inlined and works.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a solution with [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#define HUGGLE_DEBUG_1( debug ) HUGGLE_DEBUG_2( debug, 1 )
#define HUGGLE_DEBUG_2( debug, verbosity ) \
if( Huggle::Configuration::HuggleConfiguration->Verbosity >= verbosity) \
    Huggle::Syslog::HuggleLogs->DebugLog(debug, verbosity)

#define HUGGLE_DEBUG( ... ) BOOST_PP_OVERLOAD(HUGGLE_DEBUG_,__VA_ARGS__) (__VA_ARGS__)
```

It is more flexible than the approach using the comma operator, since you can use any default argument, not just `1`.

Still: Use inline functions (or Lambdas).

Comment: +1 for a less hacky solution. But note that mine could be extended to other default values as well: `4 & ~ !__VA_ARGS__`, for example.